# Accented operators using babel

Tags: babel, accents, math-operators

I'm using the `es-minimal` option in `babel` which, among other things, disables accents on operators. Since I want accented operators I used the `\accentedoperators` command however the operators remain unaccented.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-minimal]{babel}
\accentedoperators 
\begin{document}
$\lim$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file `spanish.ldf` one finds:

```
\es@genoption{es-minimal}
 {es-ucroman,es-noindentfirst,es-nosectiondot,es-noenumerate,%
  es-noitemize,es-noquoting,es-notilde,es-nodecimaldot}
 {\spanishplainpercent
  \let\es@operators\relax}
```

which shows the definition of `es-minimal` in terms of other options; in particular, `es-minimal` includes

```
\let\es@operators\relax
```

which is responsible for suppressing the effect of `\accentedoperators` once `es-minimal` is called.

One possible solution is to use directly the options of `es-minimal`except the one affecting the accents on operators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-ucroman,es-noindentfirst,es-nosectiondot,es-noenumerate,es-noitemize,es-noquoting,es-notilde,es-nodecimaldot,]{babel}

\spanishplainpercent

\begin{document}
$\lim$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use a local configuration file for the `spanish` module; this is done by writing a file `spanish.cfg` containing almost all the options for `es-minimal`, except the one for accents. The file `spanish.cfg` then would look like

```
\es@genoption{es-petminimal}
 {es-ucroman,es-noindentfirst,es-nosectiondot,es-noenumerate,%
  es-noitemize,es-noquoting,es-notilde,es-nodecimaldot}
 {\spanishplainpercent}
```

Save the file somewhere TeX can find it and then you can load `babel` using

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-petminimal]{babel}
```

this will give you accented operators and the remaining options from `es-minimal`.

Comment: Your solution work fine. So the `\accentedoperators` command won't work even if I place it after the `es-minimal` option? Can I patch in some way the `es-minimal` option definition to allow accented operators?

Comment: @petobens indeed, once es-minimal has been used, `\accentedoperators` will have no effect, as I said in my answer. For the second part of your question, you can use a local configuration files, as explained in my updated answer.

Comment: While I understand that the accented "lím" is traditional in Spanish speaking countries, I believe that “lim” is *not* an abbreviation but rather a symbol used worldwide without an accent. It took me a while switching into using “sin” instead of “sen” (which is used in our schools, because the Italian word is “seno”).

Comment: @egreg What about `max` and `min`operators (used for instance in optimization problems)? In spanish the words are written with accents: "máximo" and "mínimo". Should I write them as "máx" or "max"?

Comment: @petobens Mine was only a general comment. Do what's expected in your field; the most important thing is consistency across a document; either you accent *all* your operator names (where the accent is needed, of course) or none.