# Disable certain babel accented operators

Tags: babel, math-operators

I must confess I don't know much about how babel really works, so maybe someone can help me with a quick solution. I have the following line in my LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

By default babel replaces some operators with their accented versions, for example `\lim` looks like **lím**. I want to avoid this behavior, but only for certain operators. Namely, after calling babel, I have the following line:

```
\renewcommand{\lim}{\varprojlim}
```

So I expect `\lim` to give the corresponding symbol in my formulas, but instead I see babel's **lím** everywhere. How do I fix that?

I saw a related question [Accented operators using babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119090/accented-operators-using-babel), but my situation is different: I don't want to disable all the accented operators, I need only to replace `\lim` with `\varprojlim` (or maybe with an accented `\varprojlim`, that would be perfect :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you really want to rename `\varprojlim` to `\lim`. Anyway, you should do

```
\addto\extrasspanish{\renewcommand{\lim}{\varprojlim}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\addto\extrasspanish{\renewcommand{\lim}{\varprojlim}}

\begin{document}

\[
\lim_{i\in I}X_i
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\addto\extrasspanish{...}` works well! Thank you very much! As for renaming `\lim` to `\varprojlim`, it just saves a lot of time when I type my texts (where I never need the usual `\lim`) :-)